# IONIC 3 Can't not open PDF file in Android with @ionic-native/file-opener

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

> error {"status":9,"message":"Activity not found: No Activity found to
> handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW
> dat=content://io.ionic.starter.fileOpener2.provider/files/1600942455974.pdf
> typ=application/pdf flg=0x3 }"
>
> "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^4.20.0", "@ionic-native/file":
> "^4.20.0", "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.20.0",
> "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.20.0",
> "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0", "@ionic-native/status-bar":
> "4.20.0",

Code :

```java
let fackNama = Date.now();
      this.file.copyFile(path, 'help_guide.pdf', this.file.dataDirectory, `${fackNama}.pdf`).then(result => {
        this.fileOpener.open(result.nativeURL, 'application/pdf').then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
        .catch(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e)));
      });
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when the plugin is unable to find an application to open the specified file in. Since most phones come with a file opener in-built, I'm assuming this app is being used in a user profile that does not include a file opener.

You can try using the [showOpenWithDialog()](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2#fileopener2showopenwithdialogfilepath-mimetype-options) on the plugin. This method isn't included in Ionic Native however

Comment: Glad to hear that. Consider accepting this as the right answer. It'll be helpful for the enxt person who faces the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm using this way, you can use it**

```
downloadFile(url: string) {
    
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      this.pdfFileOpen(url, this.file.syncedDataDirectory);
    } else {
      this.pdfFileOpen(url, this.file.dataDirectory);
    }
   
  }

  pdfFileOpen(url, fileDir) {

    const pdfFileName = url.split('/')[4]
    this.file.createDir(fileDir, 'FolderName', true)
    .then(resp => {
      
      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      fileTransfer.download(url, resp.toURL() + pdfFileName)
        .then(entry => {
          
          this.fileOpener.showOpenWithDialog(resp.toURL() + pdfFileName, 'application/pdf');
        
        });

      });
  }
```